# Splitting spaces unless there's brackets in a string. Java

Tags: java

For example let's say there's a string like: "A B (C D) E"

I would like to split the string into an array list like:

1. Array1 "A"
2. Array2 "B"
3. Array3 "C D"
4. Array4 "E"

At the moment it's like this:

1. Array1 "A"
2. Array2 "B"
3. Array3 "(C"
4. Array4 "D)"
5. Array5 "E"

This is what I have to split the spaces:

```
Scanner Str = new Scanner(input); 
if (Str.hasNext())
    for(int i = 0; Str.hasNext(); i++) {
        args.add(i, Str.next());
    }
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this solves your problem

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class RegExDemo2 {

        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            String input = "A B (C D) E";
            String output = input.replaceAll("\\s\\([^)]*?\\)", "").trim();
            ArrayList<String> newoutput = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(output.split(" ")));
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

            while(m.find()) {
                newoutput.add(m.group(1));
            }
            for(String test: newoutput)
            {
                System.out.println("Array "+test);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to process the input two times. First you have to identify the content inside parenthesis and has to replace the space with new symbol |. If many parenthesis are there, then it has done in a loop. Then once you process the parenthesis, then you can split the String and finally new symbol has to replace with space. So String will change as below.

1. "A B (C D) E"
2. "A B C|D E"
3. then split, replace | and add to array list.